# почему миксин не работает

Tags: html, css, sass

Я не могу найти свою ошибку, по какой причине в одной директории виден миксин, а в другой выдает ошибку и пишет что его не существует, уже перепроверял действительно ли все работает в других местах, менял название файлов,ничего не понимаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- сниппет
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- файл с миксинами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- ошибка
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- нет ошибки
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- импорты